# I'm getting "Error during update A problem occurred during the update. " while trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, updates

I'm trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 but while upgrading, it says

```
Error during update

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry.

W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found 
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/stable/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found 
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```